# Html5 dropdown menu - make youtube video appear

Tags: css, html, youtube

first time on this forum. Im kinda new to html5 so im trying some different coding tricks. But this one i couldn't figure out. I started like this

```
<select>
<option value=">"blank">Choose one of the videos</option>
<option value=">Dronefilm1">Drone flying over city</option>
<option value=">Dronefilm2">Flying around a bridge</option>
<option value=">Drone film3">autonomous flight</option>
</select>
```

Where to i go from here? what should i write inn the css file, and how do i get the video to appear from youtube?

thanks for answering!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you should use an `iframe` to show the YouTube video!

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to do this.

You should set `event listener` to `onchange` event and then show/hide videos based on select value.

[Here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/examples/select-pizza.php) you can see example of doing something when select is changed.